# Eloquent (WITHOUT Laravel) get data from table with dynamic name

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, eloquent

I'm sure this is a totally simple question but for the life of me I'm stuck here- we're using Eloquent outside of Laravel due to PHP restrictions. I have a support ticket tracking app that I'm trying to update. 
The data structure of this app is such that each ticket is assigned a UUID on submission and a table with that UUID as its name is generated and all changes to the ticket are tracked as new entries in that table.

Following some tutorials on Eloquent I got our models and controllers set up and working but for each one I see that I'm defining the table name in the model itself. IE our ticket model is

```
namespace Models;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ticket extends Model {
   protected $table = 'tickets';
   protected $fillable = [table columns here];
}
```

and anything called in the tickets controller correctly and successfully reads and writes data to our `tickets` table.

**So... my question is: how would I go about reading/writing/creating/deleting those previously mentioned UUID tables?**

I've tried the built in table selector (ie- `DB::table(uuid here)` and `DB::setTable(uuid here)` but to no avail. I get `Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Models\Database::setTable()`

What I'm after is a model/controller that I can reuse for ANY dynamically-named table.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a generic model and dynamically set the table name, like this:

```
namespace Models;
use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class FormerUUIDTicket extends Model {
   protected $table = 'some_table';
   protected $fillable = [table columns here];
}

class SomeController
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $uuid = $_POST['uuid_field']; //some uuid, the table name
        $model = new FormerUUIDTicket;
        $model->setTable($uuid);
        return $model->get(); //do anything using eloquent with proper table
    }
}
```

Make sure that you always set the table name before use, or it will fail. Don't use static function either, for the same reason.

Comment: I see where you're going here... how could I call to this from my core action file? Like, right now when someone clicks on 'edit this ticket' it pulls the UUID for that ticket from our `tickets` table, set it as `$uuid`, and then we have a `"SELECT blah, blah, blah FROM $uuid"` query.

Comment: thanks, btw- I'm new to MVC frameworks and class relations have ALWAYS messed me up.

Comment: If I understod correctly, you will get the info as form input. Set this to `$uuid` variable and use as the code show.

Comment: AH! I think I got it.  Let me run a few tests. Thanks!!

Comment: Alright- this worked great! One little issue that I don't know if you have a solution for is that I'm getting `Strict Standards:  Non-static method Controllers\Uuids::someAction() should not be called statically in /[filepath to core actions file] `.  All of our action calls are being sent via AJAX requests from the frontend to core.php (long story)- which links up all our controllers and libraries and whatnot and then defines specific actions. These actions call the various controllers and datasets, then trigger other actions based on the return and type of action. I hope this makes sense.